# WP stopped emailing notifications about new comments

Tags: email

When I started developing the blog, WP was 3.5.1. I tested notifications about a new comment then, and it worked fine - in July 2015. Now the blog is on 4.3.1, and email notifications stopped. I do get an email notifications about a new registered user, change of admin email, etc, but nothing for comments. Provider is GoDaddy. I haven't changed anything in functions.php or other files related to emailing. I don't have any emailing plugins. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, earlier WordPress used to send notification on new comment. Not sure if that has been removed in latest version. I faced the same problem so I started using [Better Notifications for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/) plugin. I think you shall also use this.